# Linq query-dateOfBirth to age

Tags: .net, linq

Is is possible to turn a dateOfBirth in a linq query to an age within the query so i can do a comparison to an int?

Cheers in advanced

Truez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be tricky or expensive to calculate the exact age for each record. Assuming you're really wanting to say something like "find me everyone 18 or over" it would be a better idea to work out the date of birth of someone who is *exactly* 18 today, and find everyone with a date of birth less than or each to that:

```
DateTime latestAdultBirth = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-18);
var adults = people.Where(person => person.dateOfBirth < latestAdultBirth);
```